# Is it possible for directx12 to render to only a portion of a window?

Tags: wpf, directx, game-engine, directx-12

I'm trying to host a dx12 viewport in WPF, but it seems I can only render to the full window.

[image: image1]

I've tried to set D3D12VIEWPORT.Width to half of the window's width, and i got this

[image: image2]

And I've tried to set the width of the ScissorRect to half of the window, then I got this.

[image: image3]

Is there a way to draw to only part of the window and left the rest part of window for UI?

Comment: IMHO it is better to add a child (static) window to your window and position the child into the required rectangle and make DX render into it.

Comment: Well WPF doesn't allow an embeded child window. All I can do is to add child UserControl to the main window. But UserControl in WPF doesn't have a handle (I guess this is because WPF is based on directx too). I tried to embed a Winform child window which has a handle, but it seems the main WPF window can't capture messages sent by winform.

Comment: Then yoy might be able to make it work by experimenting with the viewport

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

Just in case anyone runs into the same problem when trying to make WPF and dx work together:

1.Add a WindowsFormsControlLibrary project to the solution.

2.Handles the message in a winform usercontrol by overriding WndProc.

3.Embed the winform usercontrol into WPF main window.

4.Render into the embedded winform usercontrol.